# Wrongly installed same application twice - how to recognize the latest and remove the other?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, package-management

Sorry for the stupid question, but somehow I've wrongly installed VSCode twice (probably the first time manually and the second one from the official repo), so now when searching for 'vscode' I get its icon twice

[image]

Is it just a graphical bug and there is only one version installed or are there actually two different installations?
If the second, how can I distinguish between the two installation the latest installed/most updated and remove the other?

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, GNOME 42.5.

Answer (score 0):

The launchers for apps correspond to [.desktop files](https://help.gnome.org/admin//system-admin-guide/2.32/menustructure-desktopentry.html.en).

The strategy I would use :

1. search for the corresponding .desktop files
2. check which file comes from the deb package or look into each file to see how they differ

To search for .desktop files, you can use the `find` command (eg. `sudo find / -name *.desktop`) or this python code from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615598):

```py
from gi.repository import Gio

all_apps = Gio.AppInfo.get_all()  # Returns a list of DesktopAppInfo objects (see docs)

# Print display name and .desktop file name and path for all apps
for app in all_apps:
    print(app.get_display_name())
    print(f"\t{app.get_filename()}")
```

To check whether a file comes from a package, you can use `dpkg -S /path/to/file`.